# richTextBox.DrawToBitmap Does Not Draw Containing Text?

Tags: c#, controls, drawtobitmap

If I have a richTextBox and run DrawToBitmap on it, it doesn't draw any of the text inside of the richTextBox.

```
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(rtb.Width, rtb.Height);
inputControl.DrawToBitmap(b, new Rectangle(0, 0, b.Width, b.Height));
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/1454d078-c312-4741-88df-aa7eb306fe51/) came up second in Google. Seems to have exactly what you want. Because I imagine you're using this inside your function from this question [Accepting Form Elements As Method Arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973412/accepting-form-elements-as-method-arguments/4973556#4973556), it's probably best to do something like this.

```
if(inputControl is RichTextBox)
{
    //do specifc magic here
}
else
{
    //general case
}
```

You can check for a Control containing RichTextBox recursively

```
bool ContainsOrIsRichTextBox(Control inputControl)
{
    if(inputControl is RichTextBox) return true;
    foreach(Control control in inputControl.Controls)
    {
        if(ContainsOrIsRichTextBox(control)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I haven't compiled this, and there's a way of doing it without risking a StackOverflowException, but this should get you started.

Comment: Let's say I send a panel that contains a richTextBox.  Is there a way to check if the panel contains a richTextBox?

Comment: You'd have to traverse the tree of controls. I've provided a snippet.

Answer (score 5):

I know this is relatively old, but a working solution that I found at http://www.windows-tech.info/3/8ffaf21eed5de2d4.php:

```
public static Bitmap RtbToBitmap(RichTextBox rtb)
{
    rtb.Update(); // Ensure RTB fully painted
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rtb.Width, rtb.Height);
    using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        gr.CopyFromScreen(rtb.PointToScreen(Point.Empty), Point.Empty, rtb.Size);
    }
    return bmp;
}
```

Comment: This works for me; I'm using windows forms. I have a custom transparent panel with rich text box right below it so that I can write text and draw on the same 'page'. Absolutely perfect solution!

Comment: This doesn't work ... It draws the image, but draws the SaveFileDialog-UI with it. Meaning, it draws the text, but if you load it into, say, Paint, then you will see the SaveFileDialog-Window faded into the background. Check out my answer :)

Comment: No, I didn't "add my own crap to it" ... When using your solution, it would also paint the `SaveFileDialog` with it. I painted the `RichTextBox` beforehand, so that it would not paint the `SaveFileDialog`-UI with it.

Comment: @Momoro, yes, you did. Call my function BEFOREHAND, after that, save the image and you'll see that the save file dialogue is not a part of the image. Once again: CALL THE FUNCTION **BEFORE** CALLING SaveFileDialog!!!

Answer (score 4):

From the MSDN Library article for RichTextBox.DrawToBitmap():

> This method is not relevant for this class.

A crummy way to say that the native Windows richedit control doesn't support WM_PRINT.  Taking a screen shot is an option, Novikov gave you a link to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, the later version of the RichTextBox control supports the DrawToBitmap method properly; it also improves performance and has more features.

```
internal class RichTextBox5: RichTextBox
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
           CreateParams cparams = base.CreateParams; 
           if (LoadLibrary("msftedit.dll") != IntPtr.Zero)
           {
              cparams.ClassName = "RICHEDIT50W";
           }
           return cparams;
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a related answer here: [how to print Rich text box contents on any device contenxt with proper formatting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368480/how-to-print-rich-text-box-contents-on-any-device-contenxt-with-proper-formattin)

I changed this to render my off screen RichTextBox to a bitmap. This way I could create a bitmap off screen and then send it to OpenGL.

```
    // Convert the unit used by the .NET framework (1/100 inch) 
    // and the unit used by Win32 API calls (twips 1/1440 inch)
    private const double anInch = 14.4;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct RECT
    {
        public int Left;
        public int Top;
        public int Right;
        public int Bottom;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct CHARRANGE
    {
        public int cpMin;               // First character of range (0 for start of doc)
        public int cpMax;               // Last character of range (-1 for end of doc)
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct FORMATRANGE
    {
        public IntPtr    hdc;           // Actual DC to draw on
        public IntPtr    hdcTarget;     // Target DC for determining text formatting
        public RECT      rc;            // Region of the DC to draw to (in twips)
        public RECT      rcPage;        // Region of the whole DC (page size) (in twips)
        public CHARRANGE chrg;          // Range of text to draw (see earlier declaration)
    }

    private const int WM_USER        = 0x0400;
    private const int EM_FORMATRANGE = WM_USER + 57;

    [DllImport("USER32.dll")] private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);

    /// <summary>
    /// Render the specified RichTextBox onto the specified bitmap
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="textBox">RichTextBox to render</param>
    /// <param name="bitmap">Bitmap to render the RichTextBox onto</param>
    public void RenderToBitmap(RichTextBox textBox, Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        // Set area to render to be entire bitmap
        RECT rect;
        rect.Left   = 0;
        rect.Top    = 0;
        rect.Right  = (int)(bitmap.Width  * anInch);
        rect.Bottom = (int)(bitmap.Height * anInch);

        Graphics g   = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
        IntPtr   hdc = g.GetHdc();

        FORMATRANGE fmtRange;
        fmtRange.chrg.cpMin = textBox.GetCharIndexFromPosition(new Point(0,0));
        fmtRange.chrg.cpMax = textBox.GetCharIndexFromPosition(new Point(bitmap.Width,bitmap.Height));
        fmtRange.hdc        = hdc;                  // Use the same DC for measuring and rendering
        fmtRange.hdcTarget  = hdc;
        fmtRange.rc         = rect;
        fmtRange.rcPage     = rect;

        IntPtr lparam = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(fmtRange));
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(fmtRange, lparam, false);

        // Render the control to the bitmap
        SendMessage(textBox.Handle, EM_FORMATRANGE, new IntPtr(1), lparam);

        // Clean up
        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(lparam);
        g.ReleaseHdc(hdc);
    }
```

Comment: Funny thing. Here I am 4 years later looking how to do this and what do I find? I find my own answer to this question right here. I didn't even remember writing this code! Even funnier, I found the answer below to be an even better way to do this.

Comment: I'm attempting to use this method, but am having some trouble. I want to save the bitmap to a file, but VS is throwing error 'cannot convert type 'void' to type 'bitmap'' - Is there a fix? Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I tested the methods above, and whenever I load the saved Bitmap into an ImageViewer(Like Paint), it would have the SaveFileDialog-UI faded into the background of the text. Luckily, I found an easy fix:

```
SaveFileDialog bfsd = new SaveFileDialog();       
var rtb = richTextBox1;

        bfsd.Filter = "Bitmap (*.bmp)|*.bmp|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
        bfsd.Title = "Save your text as a Bitmap File";

        rtb.Update(); // Ensure RTB fully painted
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(rtb.Width, rtb.Height);
        using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            gr.CopyFromScreen(rtb.PointToScreen(Point.Empty), Point.Empty, rtb.Size);
        }

        if (bfsd.ShowDialog()==DialogResult.OK)
        {
         Draw:
            try
            {
                bmp.Save(bfsd.FileName);

                bmp.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("An error ocurred while attempting to save your Image...", "Error! Error!", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

                if (dr == DialogResult.Retry)
                {
                    goto Draw;
                }
                else if (dr == DialogResult.Cancel)
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
```

- That way, it paints the picture before you even press `Save`(**Don't worry, it won't actually save the image until you press `Save`**)

Pressing `Cancel` doesn't effect the process, because when you press the `Button` or `MenuStripItem` to save it, it will update & re-paint it :)

I implemented a `try`-`catch` method, so that it will catch an error if one occurs, rather than the app just `(Not Responding)`

The `catch` method is a `Retry` `Button`

It will catch the error, and give you the choice to either `Cancel` the whole `Operation`, or `Retry`

I used a `goto` to be able to just rewind, and make another attempt to save the file, rather than having the `SaveFileDialog` appear again.

I hope this helps you :)